# Apache Camel HTTP Source Connector Conversion Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use CamelHttpsourceSourceConnector to read JSON data and import it into Kafka topic. Here command I use to configure connector:

```
 curl -s -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/SimpleHttpSource/config \
    -d '{
   "topics": "test",    
   "tasks.max": "1",    
   "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.httpsource.CamelHttpsourceSourceConnector",
   "camel.kamelet.http-source.url": "http://host.docker.internal:5100/v1/data",
   "camel.kamelet.http-source.contentType": "application/json",
   "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
   "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
   "value.converter.schemas.enable": false
 }'
```

JSON Payload format is

```
[
  {
    "id": "53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
    "name": "Service Account:53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
    "packages": [
      {
        "id": "53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
        "name": "Package For Service Account:53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
        "externalIdentifier": "Package Identifier For Service Account:53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
        "description": "Package Description For Service Account:53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
        "metadata": null,
        "products": [
          {
            "id": "53d27e24-87ff-4219-803b-f7f8ad662601",
            "name": "name",
            "externalIdentifier": "externalIdentifier",
            "type": 8,
            "period": {
              "start": "2024-02-19T18:31:09.4168621+02:00",
              "end": null
            },
            "status": 0,
            "path": null,
            "publicApi": false,
            "configuration": {},
            "description": "description",
            "metadata": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If JSON array contains less then 15 items everything works and event is inserted in Kakfa topic. If JSON array contains more items I get this strange error:

```
2024-02-20 18:34:44 [2024-02-20 16:34:44,738] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=SimpleHttpSource-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
2024-02-20 18:34:44 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:230)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:494)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:402)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.execute(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:367)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:77)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2024-02-20 18:34:44 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: ByteArrayConverter is not compatible with objects of type class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter.fromConnectData(ByteArrayConverter.java:63)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:67)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$6(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:494)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:180)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:214)
2024-02-20 18:34:44     ... 13 more
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?